# Dynamic count of rows between two dates based on ID in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, dynamic

I have been trying to count number of rows for each ID between dynamically changing dates.

My dataset looks following:

| Date | ID | Minimum_Date | Min + 6m | Min + 12m | Min + 18m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-31 | 1 | 2017-07-31 | 2018-01-31 | 2018-07-31 | 2019-01-31 |
| 2018-05-08 | 1 | 2017-07-31 | 2018-01-31 | 2018-07-31 | 2019-01-31 |
| 2018-11-10 | 1 | 2017-07-31 | 2018-01-31 | 2018-07-31 | 2019-01-31 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2019-07-08 | 13 | 2019-07-08 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-07-08 | 2021-01-08 |
| 2019-08-10 | 13 | 2019-07-08 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-07-08 | 2021-01-08 |
| 2019-09-19 | 13 | 2019-07-08 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-07-08 | 2021-01-08 |
| 2019-12-23 | 13 | 2019-07-08 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-07-08 | 2021-01-08 |

The result should be something similar (min date row not included in the total row count):

| ID | Minimum_Date - Min + 6m | Min + 6m - Min + 12m | Min + 12m - Min + 18m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

Normally, I would do this exercise in excel using simple Countifs, but due to dataset size, it is not possible.

All suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you’re starting with just the `Date` and `ID` columns. In that case you can construct your other columns pretty easily, with the help of `transform`:

- `groupby.transform` can get you the group’s min date in the right shape for comparisons against the `Date` column
- `series.transform` with a dictionary argument can get you a dataframe of the boundary dates you want, by shifting by a number of months every time. This must be done with `DateOffset`.

```
>>> dates = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform('min')
>>> dates
0   2017-07-31
1   2017-07-31
2   2017-07-31
4   2019-07-08
5   2019-07-08
6   2019-07-08
7   2019-07-08
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> dates = dates.transform({f'min + {n}m': lambda s, months=n: s + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=months) for n in [0, 6, 12, 18]})
>>> dates
    min + 0m   min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
0 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
1 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
2 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
4 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
5 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
6 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
7 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
```

From there comparing all those dates is easy, but requires using `.le()` and `.gt()` rather than `<=` and `>` to specify against which dimension we’re comparing:

```
>>> dates.le(df['Date'], axis='index').groupby(df['ID']).sum()
     min + 0m  min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
ID                                           
1           3         2          1          0
13          4         0          0          0
```

Those are cumulated, as in all 3 dates of ID 1 are counted in column `min + 0m` even though they are also in the next columns. We can correct that in one of 2 ways, either diffing this cumulated result:

```
>>> cumul = dates.le(df['Date'], axis='index').groupby(df['ID']).sum()
>>> cumul.diff(-1, axis='columns').fillna(cumul).astype(int)
     min + 0m  min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
ID                                           
1           1         1          1          0
13          4         0          0          0
```

The other way is by comparing that the date is less than one boundary date but greater than the next:

```
>>> dates
    min + 0m   min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
0 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
1 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
2 2017-07-31 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31
4 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
5 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
6 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
7 2019-07-08 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08
>>> next_date = dates.shift(-1, axis='columns', fill_value=pd.Timestamp.max)
>>> next_date
    min + 0m   min + 6m  min + 12m                     min + 18m
0 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
1 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
2 2018-01-31 2018-07-31 2019-01-31 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
4 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
5 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
6 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
7 2020-01-08 2020-07-08 2021-01-08 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
>>> between = dates.le(df['Date'], axis='index') & next_date.gt(df['Date'], axis='index')
>>> between
   min + 0m  min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
0      True     False      False      False
1     False      True      False      False
2     False     False       True      False
4      True     False      False      False
5      True     False      False      False
6      True     False      False      False
7      True     False      False      False
>>> between.groupby(df['ID']).sum()
     min + 0m  min + 6m  min + 12m  min + 18m
ID                                           
1           1         1          1          0
13          4         0          0          0
```